# what's another way to say, "highly sought out"

Tags: phrases, synonyms

what is another way to say " highly sought out"? I am looking for an alternative phrase for this current phrase.

Comment: Can you provide some context please?

Comment: Is it [unobtanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium), [desirable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desirable), or in high demand? Is it sought for? In short, how do you want to use this phrase?

Answer (score 3):

I would simply go with the word **covet(ed)**.

> yearn to possess or have (something).

Answer (score 0):

Something prized is often subjective but I think most here could use [quaesitum](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/272248/quaesitum) for "highly sought out" but a general term is your 'objective desire'

Comment: I'd stick with 'prized'.

Answer (score 0):

Simply say "highly sought," the past tense of "to seek." The addition of "out" is superfluous, as "sought" conveys the desire for something not already possessed. Use "out" when using the present tense, as in, "We should seek out the best person for this position." Alternatively you might say, "This position is highly sought after..." but not "...highly sought out..."

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[highly sought after](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=highly+sought+after%2Chighly+sought+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chighly%20sought%20after%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chighly%20sought%20out%3B%2Cc0)" and "highly prized."

> [As more work becomes project-based, projects grow in complexity, and clients demand accountability and efficiency, professionals with project management have become highly sought after.](http://scs.georgetown.edu/programs_nc/CE0101/project-management?dID=5)
>
> [They labor deep into the morning hours pulling squeegees in garages and warehouses, screen printing beautiful posters that have become highly prized.](http://academics.utep.edu/Default.aspx?tabid=62896)

Answer (score 0):

"*In (great) demand*" or "*Hot property*"

Answer (score 0):

With other adjectives directly related to seeking:

> Exquisite:  sought out, fine and dear
>
> Recherché:  rare, choice, sought out

You could also rework the sentence using a noun which suggests the desirable qualities sought:

> Paragon:  a model of excellence or perfection "We are looking for a paragon of good taste."
>
> Apotheosis:  the perfect example "We seek the apotheosis of the resolute factotum."